# Keep absolute content's position inside scrollable div

Tags: html, css

I know this is a question that was asked many times, but I cannot find exactly my scenario. I want to put an overlay over a scrollable div. I cannot put it outside the scrolling container because it would disable it's scrolling possibilities. Using `pointer-events: none` isn't possible, since I want the content to by blocked from mouse events.

```css
#con{
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  
  position: relative;
}

#content{
}

.fade{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.spinnerContainer {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
```

```html
<p>
    Some Content before
</p>

<div id="con">
    <div id="content">
        I need the mouseevents on me to be blocked but still being scrollable.<br>
        The overlay should keep it's position and shouldn't scroll with me.
        <br><br>
        DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY
        CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY
        CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY
        CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY
        CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY
        CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY
        CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY
        CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY
        CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY
        CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY
        CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY
        CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>
    </div>
    <div class="fade">
        <div class="spinnerContainer">
            <div>
                [Spinner-Image here]
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<p>
    Some Content after
</p>
```

Is someone able to adopt it to my needs?

Comment: I don't understand. You want the overlay to *not* scroll with the content then why not putting it out of the scrollable element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `pseudo` element (`::after`) for this. I added the `:after` to the `#a` element. You can remove the `#b` element altogether.

Since the `pseudo` element will be essentially at a higher z-index, it will block mouse events on the content.

```css
#con {
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: relative;
}

#a {
  position: relative;
}

#a::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Some Content before
</p>

<div id="con">
  <div id="a">
    I need the mouseevents on me to be blocked but still being scrollable.<br> The overlay should keep it's position and shouldn't scroll with me.
    <br><br> DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY
    CONTENT
    <br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY
    CONTENT
    <br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY
    CONTENT
    <br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY
    CONTENT
    <br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>
  </div>
</div>
<p>
  Some Content after
</p>
```

### EDIT FOR UPDATED QUESTION

```css
.con-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

#con {
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: relative;
}

#content {
  position: relative;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}

#content::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.spinnerContainer {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  z-index: 5;
}

.spinnerContainer img {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Some Content before
</p>

<div class="con-wrapper">
  <div id="con">
    <div id="content">
      I need the mouseevents on me to be blocked but still being scrollable.<br> The overlay should keep it's position and shouldn't scroll with me.
      <br><br> DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT
      <br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT
      <br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT
      <br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT
      <br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT
      <br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT
      <br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT
      <br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT
      <br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT
      <br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT
      <br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT
      <br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>DUMMY CONTENT<br>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="spinnerContainer">
    <img src="https://c.tenor.com/tEBoZu1ISJ8AAAAC/spinning-loading.gif" width="50" height="30">
  </div>
</div>
<p>
  Some Content after
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for your great recommendation! But I simplified my example a bit too much (adopted it now). Inside the fade container, there is actually even more content (even content that might be data-bound via Angular). Still any idea how to realize this?

Comment: I see you updated your question. What is the `fade` container? I'm not sure I understand your exact needs.

Comment: Just renamed the elements to make it more clear. The job of this container is actually to make the content look like it's loading. The fade-container contains images, maybe data-bound content etc. So I can't just use an after pseudo element I guess.

Comment: You can use the `pseudo` element. Where should the `spinner` be placed. You don't need to put the background on the `fade` element.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to explain more exactly. Just check my latest example. You'll see there is a pseudo-image "[Spinner-Image here]" now centered via css flex inside the red fading container. I need these elements to stay in position when the div is scrolled.

Comment: So the spinner should stay over the content but stay in the same position as the container scrolls? For instance, if the spinner is in the middle (centered vertically and horizontally), and stays there as the content scrolls?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm looking for. I need flex centered contents inside the (red) fading-container. Since in my solution there are even data-bound components, I cannot relay on pseudo elements.

Comment: @tris I updated my answer. I added a wrapping container to your content. This will allow you to place an element over the scrolling content, keeping it centered while the user scrolls. You can put whatever you want inside of the `spinnerContainer` element. It's a combination of a `psuedo` element for the overlay, and then absolutely positioning the spinner over the content.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort! I can try to adopt your solution to my project but I guess it will be very tricky since I use an Angular directive that just adds some Html-Content as very list child to it's container. Is there no chance achieving this using a solution that is more _compatible_ to mine? By just modifying it's CSS?

Comment: There's really no way to use CSS only for this if you can't modify the HTML to add that wrapping container. Basically you really need a wrapper on the `#con` element for this to work.

Comment: So this is probably best practice. Thank you!